# GPU not detected by Keras/Tensorflow on AWS ml.p2.xlarge instance managed by SageMaker

Tags: keras, gpu, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using a custom Docker container for use with SageMaker on a `ml.p2.xlarge` instance.

The base image is [tiangolo/python-machine-learning:cuda9.1-python3.7](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/python-machine-learning), which normally comes with the required CUDA toolkit. The python packages are installed via conda using the following minimalist `environment.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  - boto3
  - joblib
  - keras
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - tensorflow=2.0
```

But when I run the training job for a small `lenet5` CNN, I don't see any GPU activity in the logs (and the training last as long as on a non-GPU instance).

More worrying, `len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')` returns `0`, and `K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()` is empty. Finally, if I inspect device placement (using `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)`) on a basic operation such as the following:

```
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```

I get

```
Executing op _MklMatMul in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

Confirming that the operation has taken place on the CPU.

At first I thought my use case was too light to trigger GPU usage, but it seems the GPU is not detected at all! Am I missing any steps or components required for this to work?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to start with the SageMaker-provided environments to make sure you have a tested, recent, and production-ready setup. In particular, for Tensorflow and Keras that is:

- On SageMaker Notebooks, the `conda_tensorflow_p*` jupyter kernels
- For SageMaker Training and inference tasks, the TensorFlow Framework
  container ([container on github](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container), [orchestration with python sdk](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html))

Comment: Thanks. In a SageMaker notebook instance, the GPU is apparently detected.
In terms of standalone training jobs however, I created a container from the `sageMaker TensorFlow container` you linked to, specifying the GPU version and providing the `tensorflow-gpu 2.1.0` wheel, everything GPU thus, but to no avail!

Comment: can you try using the sagemaker SDK? it will automatically use the right docker image under the hood https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_tf.html#train-a-model-with-tensorflow

Comment: I'll give it a try but the initial aim was to run training jobs from the dashboard without a programmatic intervention, which then requires me to design the right image myself :)

Comment: Which dashboard are you referring to? the amazon sagemaker console?

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0):

We need to install all necessary cuda, and other graphic driver in order to make it work.
Consider the following steps from the SageMaker TensorFlow [dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-training-toolkit/blob/master/docker/1.15.2/py3/Dockerfile.gpu), such as:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-dev \
    ca-certificates \
    cuda-command-line-tools-10-0 \
    cuda-cublas-dev-10-0 \
    cuda-cudart-dev-10-0 \
    cuda-cufft-dev-10-0 \
    cuda-curand-dev-10-0 \
    cuda-cusolver-dev-10-0 \
    cuda-cusparse-dev-10-0 \
    curl \
    libcudnn7=7.5.1.10-1+cuda10.0 \
    # TensorFlow doesn't require libnccl anymore but Open MPI still depends on it
    libnccl2=2.4.7-1+cuda10.0 \
    libgomp1 \
    libnccl-dev=2.4.7-1+cuda10.0 \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libhdf5-serial-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzmq3-dev \
    git \
    wget \
    vim \
    build-essential \
    openssh-client \
    openssh-server \
    zlib1g-dev \
    # The 'apt-get install' of nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1804-5.0.2-ga-cuda10.0
    # adds a new list which contains libnvinfer library, so it needs another
    # 'apt-get update' to retrieve that list before it can actually install the
    # library.
    # We don't install libnvinfer-dev since we don't need to build against TensorRT,
    # and libnvinfer4 doesn't contain libnvinfer.a static library.
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated  \
    nvinfer-runtime-trt-repo-ubuntu1804-5.0.2-ga-cuda10.0 \
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated  \
    libnvinfer5=5.0.2-1+cuda10.0 \
 && rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer_plugin* \
 && rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvcaffe_parser* \
 && rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvparsers* \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
```

Run all those commands above and retry if you can find GPUs